# Material-UI Autocomplete onChange not updates value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use `onChange` event on Autocomplete component to get current selected values.
The problem is that it does not working as expected, so when I click to check/uncheck value checkbox is still unchecked but in console i can see that new value was added

uncoment this part to make it works:

```
  value={myTempVal}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setMyTempVal(newValue);
        console.log(newValue);
      }}
```

online demo:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/hardcore-snowflake-7chnc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

code:

```
const [myTempVal, setMyTempVal] = React.useState([]);

<Autocomplete
      open
      multiple
      value={myTempVal}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setMyTempVal(newValue);
        console.log(newValue);
      }}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      disablePortal
      renderTags={() => null}
      noOptionsText="No labels"
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => {
        return (
          <>
            <Checkbox
              icon={icon}
              checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
              style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
              checked={selected}
            />
            {option.title}
          </>
        );
      }}
      options={option2}
      // groupBy={option => option.groupName}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      renderInput={params => (
        <div>
          <div>
            <SearchIcon />
          </div>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            ref={params.InputProps.ref}
            inputProps={params.inputProps}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    />
```

Comment: You should update the code in question to include the whole function, as the issue is with the variables defined in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get `donors` `receivers` and `options` variables out of the function. Those variables get re-created at each render, this means that their reference changes at each render, and as Autocomplete makes a reference equality check to decide if an option is selected he never finds the options selected.

```
const donors = [...new Set(data.map(row => row.donor))].map(row => {
  return {
    groupName: "Donors",
    type: "donor",
    title: row || "null"
  };
});
const receivers = [...new Set(data.map(row => row.receiver))].map(row => {
  return {
    groupName: "Receivers",
    type: "receiver",
    title: row || "null"
  };
});
const option2 = [...donors, ...receivers];

export const App = props => {

  const [myTempVal, setMyTempVal] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      open
      multiple
...
```

You can also add `getOptionSelected` to overwrite the reference check :

```
<Autocomplete
      open
      multiple
      disableCloseOnSelect
      disablePortal
      renderTags={() => null}
      noOptionsText="No labels"
      getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.title === value.title} 
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => {
        return (
          <>
            <Checkbox
              icon={icon}
              checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
              style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
              checked={selected}
            />
            {option.title}
          </>
        );
      }}
      options={option2}
      // groupBy={option => option.groupName}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      renderInput={params => (
        <div>
          <div>
            <SearchIcon />
          </div>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            ref={params.InputProps.ref}
            inputProps={params.inputProps}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help:
Replace

```
checked={selected}
```

To

```
checked={myTempVal.filter(obj=>obj.title===option.title).length!==0}
```

The complete solution

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank";
import CheckBoxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckBox";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;

const data = [
  { donor: "Trader Joe's", receiver: "Person-to-Person" },
  { donor: "Trader Joe's", receiver: "Homes with Hope" },
  { donor: "Santa Maria", receiver: "Gillespie Center" },
  { donor: "Santa Maria", receiver: null }
];

export const App = props => {
  const donors = [...new Set(data.map(row => row.donor))].map(row => {
    return {
      groupName: "Donors",
      type: "donor",
      title: row || "null"
    };
  });
  const receivers = [...new Set(data.map(row => row.receiver))].map(row => {
    return {
      groupName: "Receivers",
      type: "receiver",
      title: row || "null"
    };
  });
  const option2 = [...donors, ...receivers];

  const [myTempVal, setMyTempVal] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      open
      multiple
      value={myTempVal}

      disableCloseOnSelect
      disablePortal
      renderTags={() => null}
      noOptionsText="No labels"
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => {
        return (
          <>
            <Checkbox
            onClick={
              ()=>{
                if(myTempVal.filter(obj=>obj.title===option.title).length!==0){
                  setMyTempVal([...myTempVal.filter(obj=>obj.title!==option.title)],console.log(myTempVal))
                }else{
                  setMyTempVal([...myTempVal.filter(obj=>obj.title!==option.title),option],console.log(myTempVal))
                }

              }
            }
              icon={icon}
              checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
              style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
              checked={myTempVal.filter(obj=>obj.title===option.title).length!==0}
            />
            {option.title}
          </>
        );
      }}
      options={option2}
      // groupBy={option => option.groupName}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      renderInput={params => (
        <div>
          <div>
            <SearchIcon />
          </div>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            ref={params.InputProps.ref}
            inputProps={params.inputProps}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    />
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: It's more like a hack than real solution, also this solution does not solves problem with unchecking values one they are selected

Comment: Remove the onChange method, and add an onClick on Checkbox like in the complete solution

Answer (score 0):

It is bit late to Answer this question but it might help someone.

In your code you have added onChange event in Autocomplete. When you click on checkbox it will trigger 2 times, one for checkbox and one for Autocomplte. Hence 2nd time trigger makes again checkbox unchecked so u get value in console but still checkbox is empty.

You can remove your checkbox in renderOption and use checked and uncheked icon instaed of checkbox.

```
renderOption={(option, { selected }) => {
        return (
           <React.Fragment>
            {selected ? <CheckedIcon> : <uncheckedIcon>}
            <div>
            {option.title}
            </div>
           </React.Fragment>
          </>
        );
      }}
```